# Toggle Range of Boolean Values in System.Collection.Generic.Dictonary

Tags: powershell, dictionary

Let's assume the following Dictonary:

```
$Grid = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[System.String],[System.Boolean]]]::new()
For ( $i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++ ) {
  For ( $j = 0; $j -lt 10; $j++ ) {
    $Grid.Add("$i,$j", $false)
  }
}
```

That makes a 10x10 "Grid" with some sort of Coordinates:

```
0,0 = False
0,1 = False
0,2 = False
```

and so on.

I am able to set a range of them to a specific value:

```
$Grid['0,0', '0,1', '0,2'] = $true
```

But i can't get it to work to toggle the actual value.

What i try to accomplish is something like

```
$Grid['0,0', '0,1', '0,2'] = -Not $_.Value
```

Any help is highly appreciated! - Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

You're **NOT** able to assign a value to a range of indices in the way i wrote.
Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70216395/4220118) answer from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for more details.

Comment: Btw, even `$Grid['0,0', '0,1', '0,2'] = $true` does _not_ work for me in PowerShell 7.2 (cannot test in Windows Powershell), and it seems that this is by design: _assigning_ to an indexed expression only works with a _single_ index / key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to access the entries *individually*:

```sh
'0,0', '0,1', '0,2' | ForEach-Object { $Grid[$_] = -not $Grid[$_] }
```

The reason is:

- **Using *multiple* indices / keys** using **index notation** (such as `['0,0', '0,1', '0,2']`) **only works for *getting* elements / values, not also for *setting*.**<sup>[1]</sup>
  (Even if that worked, you wouldn't be able to refer to the target elements' / entries' *existing* value, and would therefore limit you to assigning the *same, fixed* value to all targets)

---

<sup>[1] As of PowerShell 7.2, while the **error message** in response to attempting such an assignment is explicit for *arrays* (`assignment to slices is not supported.`, leaving aside that the term *slices* isn't really used in PowerShell), it is confusing for *dictionaries* (which includes hashtables): `Unable to index into an object of type <dictionary-type>`. Similarly, attempting to assign to a property of a collection's elements via [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) - which isn't supported either - results in a confusing error message -see [GitHub issue #5271](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271).</sup>

Comment: You're absolutely right. I somehow made a mistake when i first assigned a value to a couple of indices. Your answer helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BaBa.